# Excel formula - 2 out of 3 conditions met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I need help with producing a formula in Excel where 2 out of 3 conditions met and then have it perform a calculation accordingly. Example below

If Cell =“certain text” and either “option1” or “option 2” then multiply the answer by 90%. If only one option met then multiply answer by 50%
Thank you.

Comment: If all 3? If none?

Comment: Just to be clear, the first cell must = "center text" before ever interrogating option1/option2 values, correct?

Comment: As LarryBud suggests, this needs a little more clarity on possible outcomes.  I read this to mean, if no conditions are met, then it's 100%. Is that correct?  If 1st and either 2nd or 3rd condition is met than 50%, if only 1st condition, then 90%.

Comment: AND function and OR function?

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this :

```
=IF((condition1=TRUE)+(condition2=TRUE)+(condition3=TRUE)=2,TRUE,FALSE)
```

You might need to enclose the conditions in parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I can't quite get this to work. I want to add a formula where if 2 out of 3 conditions are met, it will multiply the Net cell by 90% but if conditions are not met then it will multiply the net cell by 50%. Hope this makes sense. I have updated the formula you provided below with with some info. 
For info, J14 is a Net cell. 

IF((F14="property name")+(G14="staffing)+(G11=""cleaning")=2,J14*9,J14*5

Comment: Without seeing your spreadsheet, the only remark I can give is that `90%=0.9` etc. You would need to upload a small example for me to examine, with an explanation as to what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are saying that you are looking for condition 1 to be true AND either condition 2 OR 3.

If so,...

```
if(C12="something",IF(OR(D12,E12), B12*.9, B12*.5),B12)
```

This is assuming B12 is the answer to operate on and C12 has some text to match on ("something") and the second and third conditions are in D12 and E12, respectively.  You should be able to fill in what you want to happen based on results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. Sorry if I didn't it very clear. 
I have tried your formula and it works if one condition is met, which is great but I wanted it to work if two out of the three possible conditions are met. I have put an example of the formula I adapted below. For info, J14 a Net cell. 

IF(F14="property name",IF(OR(G14="staffing",G14="cleaning"),J14*0.9,J14*0.5),J14)

Comment: The way my formula was written, if the first condition does NOT match, the result is 100%.  If the first condition matches and no other, then 50%.  If the first condition matches plus one of the other two, then 90%.  It gives an idea of a complicated "IF" with an embedded "OR".  It sounds like you really want 2 out of 3.

Comment: I am still not getting what you want.  You say 2/3, then HarryMC's answer is correct.  The only possible correction (depends on your needs) is to modify the "=2" to ">2".  If you are looking for logic like mine, then read my explanation and adapt it.  I still can't figure out exactly what you are looking without some sample data and more detailed explanation.  You need to cover all the scenarios and requirements.  For example, what happens if all 3 are true.  Does it matter that the 2nd and 3rd are true, but the 1st is false?  Sorry, trying to understand.